# Get WSUS Update Size (PowerShell)

Tags: c#, powershell, windows-update

We want to get the aggregate size of required updates for clients, which use WSUS. It can be viewed via the GUI, by going to the File Information of the update. We want to be able to do it programmatically, preferably via PowerShell, but any old way will do.

We have checked the PowerShell UpdateServices Module, and can get the list of updates with the UpdateID. However, there is no filesize attribute on Update object. [PowerShell UpdateServices Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/updateservices/get-wsusupdate?view=win10-ps)

We have also investigated the IUpdate Class for WSUS 3.0, but it also does not have a filesize attribute. See [Microsoft Docs - WSUS 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms752700(v=vs.85))

We have not browsed the database (WID), but the DB Views provided by the WSUS 3.0 API does not have the update size for the update records.

Essentially, what we are trying to achieve is determine the download size for clients for approved updates. Open to alternative solutions. If anyone can guide the way to where the filesize information is kept (either in the DB or as an object attribute) it would be appreciated.